# Why do I get a incorrect syntax exception when I am trying to connect to a SQL server?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to connect to a SQL server from a web form but getting an incorrect syntax exception in the code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HRMSConnectionString1"].ToString());
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from persons where User_Id="+uid.Text+"and Password!="+pswd.Text, cn);

        cn.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);   //exception in this line
        rdr.Read();
        Response.Write(rdr[0].ToString()); 
    }
}
```

Please guide me where m going wrong.

Comment: Something you need to be aware of is [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection) your code is vulnerable to this type of attack and thus is not secure at all, Once you've got the code working, try entering this as a password: `'OR 1=1--` . It's too complex a ubject to discuss in a comment but look into the [SQLCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) object and do some reading. Until you've done that, you absolutely should NOT be using this code in any real system.

Comment: Also, you're storing your password in "Plain Text" which means both you and anyone who manages to break into your database can read the full password of every user - Not secure. For more information, see [This article](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/103002-1.aspx) for an introduction to the topic

Answer (score 0):

The database wants to see quotes around the strings:

```
"select * from persons where User_Id='"+uid.Text+"'and Password!='"+pswd.Text+"'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"Select * from persons where [User_Id] ='"+uid.Text+"'and [Password] <> '"+pswd.Text + "'"
```

Also: [Protect your parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)! This is a must in order to prevent against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using this **!=**  operator for the purpose of Not-Equal, however that's in the progamming language. For Sql, you need to use **<>** operator

Also looks like you are using sql query with + which must be avoided under any cicumstances.

So your final code (in rough) should look like this

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from persons where User_Id='@userid'
  and Password<>'@password'",cn);        
  cmd.Parameters.Add(@userid,uid.Text);
  cmd.Parameters.Add(@password,pswd.Text);
  cn.Open();        
  SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);   
  rdr.Read();        
  Response.Write(rdr[0].ToString());
```

(Also I am not sure what is the purpose of this query, but you are fetching * and then only using one value. If you just want to check one value, you can use query like

```
Select count(1) from persons where User_Id='@userid' and Password<>'@password'
```

and then use it with ExecuteScalar method. Just a suggestion.